# Int[] Reverse - What does this actually do?

Tags: c#, arrays

I was just having a play around with some code in LINQPad and noticed that on an int array there is a Reverse method.

Usually when I want to reverse an int array I'd do so with

```
Array.Reverse(myIntArray);
```

Which, given the array `{1,2,3,4}` would then return `4` as the value of `myIntArray[0]`.

When I used the `Reverse()` method directly on my int array:

```
myIntArray.Reverse();
```

I notice that `myIntArray[0]` still comes out as `1`.

What is the `Reverse` method actually doing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`myIntArray.Reverse()` is the extension method [Enumerable.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) which returns an [IEnumerable<int>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) of the reversed array elements. It does not modify the array in-place as it [Array.Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx) does.